# Android Fixed Tabs on a Processing PApplet

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs, processing

I am developing an Android app based on [Processing](http://processing.org)

I would like to show two Fixed Tabs with some content when Menu Button is pressed.
Tab1 would contain some settings and maybe a Help Button
Tab2 should have a ListView to show a list of presets.
Now I am trying to create two TextViews for sake of simplicity.
I am trying with the approach of the Ketai library for [KetaiList](https://code.google.com/p/ketai/source/browse/trunk/ketai/src/ketai/ui/KetaiList.java)
So there's an inner class that extends TabHost inside the PApplet class extended by my application:

```
 public class MyProcessingApp extends PApplet {

  public void setup() {
  }
  public void draw() {
  }

  public void keyPressed() {  
    if (key == CODED) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        TabHost th = new GBTab(this);
      }
    }
  }

  public class GBTab extends TabHost {
    private PApplet parent;
    TabHost self;
    TabWidget tab1, tab2;
    LinearLayout layout;

    public GBTab(PApplet _parent) {

      super(_parent.getApplicationContext());
      parent = _parent;
      init();
    }

    public void init() {
      println("GBTab init");
      self = this;
      layout = new LinearLayout(parent);
      TabSpec settingsSpec = self.newTabSpec("SETTINGS").setContent(
      new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
          TextView tv = new TextView(parent);
          tv.setText("SETTINGS!");
          return tv;
        }
      }
      )
        .setIndicator("SETTINGS");
      self.addTab(settingsSpec);
      TabSpec presetsSpec = self.newTabSpec("PRESETS").setContent(
      new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
          TextView tv = new TextView(parent);
          tv.setText("PRESETS!");
          return tv;
        }
      }
      )
        .setIndicator("PRESETS");
      self.addTab(presetsSpec);
      self.setCurrentTab(0);

      parent.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          parent.addContentView(self, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }
      }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This code gives a NullPointerException when adding a tab to the TabHost.

```
self.addTab(settingsSpec);
```

since self is null.
Is this a valid approach?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it is possible for 'self' to be null since self.newTabSpec() before self.addTab() works... Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the second answer (24 votes) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685257/android-tabhost-addtab-null-pointer-exception)? Essentially it says that since you are not using a tabactivity you need to call self.setup(); before adding any tabs

Comment: That's right. I searched a lot but didn't find it. Thank you!